# How to use :before to add <use> for <svg> tags?

Tags: html, css, svg

couldn't find an example that uses css `:before` to add `<use>` inside a `<svg>` tag. So far I've tried:

```
.icon-test:before {
  content : '<use xlink:href="test.svg#icon-test"></use>';
}

.icon-test:before {
  content : '\003Cuse xlink\003Ahref\003D\0022test\002Esvg\0023icon-test\0022\003E\003C\002Fuse\003E';
}

<svg class="icon-test"></svg>
```

Does anybody know the correct way to do it? Or this is not possible?

Basically the end result should yield something like:

```
<svg class="icon-test">
  <use xlink:href="test.svg#icon-test"></use>
</svg>
```

But I want to simplify the usage by using `:before`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little more detail compared to [Jarosław Goszowski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28503888/3128209):

The `::before` and `::after` pseudoelements create a new CSS layout box as the first or last child of the CSS layout box for the element(s) matched by the rest of the selector.

The `::` notation distinguishes pseudoelement selectors from pseudoclass selectors, and [is supported in all browsers after IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent) (in other words, all browsers that will support inline SVG).  The single `:` syntax is only supported for backwards-compatibility.

The psuedo-elements **do not** create new elements in the DOM, and cannot be used to insert markup.  They only affect CSS layout.  The content is injected *after* the HTML markup has been parsed.  You cannot even use HTML entities like `&amp;`; you definitely cannot use entire element markup.

Because they only affect CSS layout, pseudo-elements can only exist for elements whose content follows the CSS layout model.  That means you *cannot* have pseudo-elements for:

- `<img>` and `<video>` elements (the content of the element is replaced by the external file, it does not have a CSS layout model);
- `<input>` and `<select>` elements (the content is replaced by the form widgets created by the browser, no CSS layout model);
- SVG elements (the content is drawn according to SVG rules, not CSS layout).

So there are two reasons why you cannot use pseudoelements to inject your `<use>` elements: one, pseudoelements don't have an effect on SVG; two, even if they did, pseudoelements can only be used to inject plain text (or complete image files), not markup.

Answer (score 1):

1. use ::before
2. is not possible. You will receive text;